# ggplot2 confidence ellipse shape incomplete

Tags: r, ggplot2, ellipse, cran, confidence-interval

I have a dataset which has a categorical variable and two continuous variables. I am attempting to make a scatterplot with confidence ellipses. However, one of the ellipses looks like a pac man, for lack of a better explanation. Also, I am not certain I am making an ellipse for the confidence intervals.

Here is my data file on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fal6x9jzk5kvafl/cv12.csv

Here is my code

```
qplot(data = cv12, x = x, y = y, colour = taxa) + 
  stat_ellipse(geom = "polygon", alpha = 1/2, aes(fill = taxa)) + 
  coord_fixed() + 
  xlim(-5,5) + 
  ylim(-4.5,4.5) + 
  scale_fill_manual (values=c("blue2","gray16","red2","#a65628","purple2")) + 
  scale_colour_manual (values=c("blue2","gray16","red2","#a65628","purple2"))
```

The purple ellipse is shaped like pac-man, but everything else looks okay. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: you're clipping the plot region too tight with xlim

Comment: ugh, always something obvious. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As baptiste noted, you probably wanted to do this:

```
qplot(data = dat, x = x, y = y, colour = colour) + 
    stat_ellipse(geom = "polygon", alpha = 1/2, aes(fill = colour)) + 
    coord_fixed(xlim = c(-5,5),ylim = c(-4.5,4.5)) +
    scale_fill_manual (values=c("blue2","gray16","red2","#a65628","purple2")) + 
    scale_colour_manual (values=c("blue2","gray16","red2","#a65628","purple2"))
```

`xlim()` and `ylim()` drop observations *up front* and they are never included in any layers at all. Hence the weird looking ellipse, because you're actually missing values.

Setting `xlim` and `ylim` in `coord_fixed()` (or more commonly `coord_cartesian()`) will clip the plot after the fact.

Comment: actually, it's a bit of a design flaw I think, because it's not the _data_ themselves that are dropped here, but those points generated internally by the stat function for the drawing of polygons (ellipses).

Comment: @baptiste That's a good point. I'm not sure I agree that the behavior should be different, but I think the documentation for `xlim()` and `ylim()` should be clearer about this.

Comment: I suppose the behaviour is fine, yes, though I think the ordering of the path should be maintained so that it's at least a convex polygon that's being drawn near the clipping borders.